# Integrate AWS Cognito with Google Workspace using SAML integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml, saml-2.0, google-workspace

I have some applications served to my company users on EKS (i.e., Jenkins). In company we use Google Workspaces (GSuite) for email and stuff. So I want to allow users to login with Google creds to those applications I serve. I figured out I could use Cognito to achieve it but I cannot connect those and flow end with Google showing **403. Error: app_not_configured_for_user**. In their [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301076?hl=en) I can find:

> Verify that the value in the saml:Issuer tag in the SAMLRequest matches the Entity ID value configured in the SAML Service Provider Details section in the Admin console. This value is case-sensitive.

but how do I debug it? I do not see a logs from neither AWS and Google sides :/

I [think](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-third-party-saml-idp/) I [followed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-saml-idp.html) all [possible](https://alsmola.medium.com/alb-authentication-with-g-suite-saml-using-cognito-858e35564dc8) guides and I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. I found that Google has [this page](https://support.google.com/a/table/9217027?p=saml_apps&hl=en-GB&visit_id=637824413400944075-2779246935&rd=1) but they do not provide exact scenario for AWS Cognito. Anyways all of those are very similar so I guess I shouldn't have problems, but I do have.

What I did:

- In Google Admin (one for workspaces) I created "Web and mobile app" of SAML type
- I downloaded metadata file
- In AWS Cognito console I created User Pool
- I created IdP provider and uploaded metadata file there
- I created application client
- Using those values I filled fields **ACS URL** and **Entity ID** in Google Admin using values:

  - ACS URL: `https://my-domain-i-just-created.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse`
  - Entity ID: `urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-1_myPoolId`
- I also selected **Name ID format** to be Persisted
- In attribute mapping I mapped email value to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`.
- In AWS Cognito I enabled HostedUI and also created mapping of `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` to email field.

And now when I click *View Hosted UI* in AWS console it will redirect me to Google authentication and after it directly to before mentioned **403 app_not_configured_for_user** page.

I tied it 3 times with slightly different configurations of mapping, signed responses, etc. but nothing gets me past that error.

Anyone tried to integrate it?

Comment: The error message you are getting from the Google side is related to the Entity ID. Have you checked if the Entity ID value from Amazon is the same you have configured in the Admin console? Also check if you have not added any extra space at the beginning or end of the Entity ID value because it is case sensitive.

Comment: I checked it multiple times. In AWS Cognito console my User pool ID is `us-east-1_IkXoxwSku` so in Google Admin I added Entity ID as `urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-1_IkXoxwSku` and I checked for whitespaces.

Comment: Maybe Amazon is requesting the Entity ID in a different format. Let me post some troubleshooting steps you can take as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to troubleshoot the 403 app_not_configured_for_user error related to SAML apps from the Google Workspace Admin console

The first thing you need to do is to grab a HAR file recording the whole login process and find the SAML request. Steps can be found [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/).

Once you get the file you can open it using that tool and search for SAMLreq at the top right (see image).

[image]

After that you will get a list of values containing information. You will have to check one by one until you find the one that has the SAML request in the request tab (see example below).

[image]

Once you get the value from the SAML request, copy it and you can use [this tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/encode_decode/) to do a SAML decode and find the entity ID. You can use Ctrl + F and search for saml:Issuer to find the value faster. If the value does not match, then you know you have an error and you will need to contact the support team from the app to see which value is the correct one.

In case the value matches I would recommend [opening a ticket](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) to check with Google.

Comment: I feel stupid now that I didn't check requests before. So thanks for that hint @Fernando! I checked requests and all seams to look ok. I already contacted support. I'll paste more details when I have them. BTW 403 page provides SAMLRequest field so It's even simpler to check it - you just need to do SAML Decode on part of error message.

Comment: I'll mark that response as correct. One more comment here is that "Name ID format" in Google Admin Console has to be set to ENTITY not PERSISTENT as AWS documentation says.

Comment: @Mateusz could you please elaborate as to why the Name ID format should be set to "ENTITY"? Or send a link to a documentation that says to configure it this way?

Comment: ^ answering my own question - when I've decoded SAML request sent from Cognito to Google, I've found this attribute of `saml2:Issuer` element: `Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"`, so looks like this should be set to `ENTITY` indeed.